# Independence and matching number of a tree

Tags: graph-theory

In a problem it was to be shown that the following equation holds for trees of $n$ vertices :
$$\alpha(T) + \beta(T) = n$$

I think that this has some relation to Konig's theorem stating that:

$$\beta(G)  = \alpha'(G)$$

for bipartite graphs $G$ where $\alpha'(G)$ is the size of the minimal vertex cover.

I don't know where to start from this.

Comment: Show that the complement of a independent set is a vertex cover and vice versa.

Comment: I think that might be an overkill but I'll give it a try.